# CSS/JQuery animate DIV on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code where I'm hiding content under a button, and on click on the button, the div with the content will show up

Example code here
https://codepen.io/deelite310/pen/BPyORp

code:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
$("#panel").toggleClass("noshow");
});
```

What I want to do is have the div #panel to animate as it appears below the button when clicked. Right now, it just "pops" in when clicked. What can I change to make this happen?

Example: want it to animate to max-height of the panel

I tried using animate, but I don't understand how to make it animate (ie height) to show the content.

Comment: Your question is very broad. What kind of animation you want to achieve. I guess the most basic one would be [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) Take a look at the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can use such code :

```
$('#panel').slideToggle(1000,'easeOutBounce');
```

Sample working code with your images : http://jsfiddle.net/ok7125dz/

Comment: unfortunately this does not work with my onlick toggleClass.

Comment: you want to toggle for showing/hiding the images when clicking twice the button ? My code is doing that...you don't need toggleClass anymore

Comment: the issue is that the content is hidden at a certain viewport (under 768px). Otherwise its displayed fully above that. I need to toggle class on Panel so that it disappears when its below 768px and show on click.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#panel").toggle(".noshow");
```

instead of

```
$("#panel").toggleClass("noshow");
```

Comment: nice, how can i stop it from animating from the left and down? just want to animate it down. though if i go over 768 px viewport, and had made the panel disappear, it remains as display: none;

Comment: $('#panel').slideToggle(1000,'easeOutBounce'); is doing an animation down, cf http://jsfiddle.net/ok7125dz/...

Answer (score 0):

Here it is what you are looking for :
`

```
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="panel"></div>

#button{
  background-color:red;
  height:40px;
  width:80px;
}

#panel{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  background-color:green;
  height:40px;
  width:80px;
}
.moveObject{ 
  -webkit-transition:1s;
  left:100px !important;
  opacity:1 !important;
}

$("#button").on("click",function(){
  $("#panel").toggleClass("moveObject");
});
```

`

Comment: thanks, however if I click on the button again, the panel doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you're interested in a sliding action you can try this simple, yet not very elegant code:

CSS:

```
   #panel {
      text-align: center; 
      width: 100%;
      transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
      max-height: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
   }
```

JS:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
 if (!$('#panel').hasClass("clicked")) {
   $("#panel").css("max-height", "500px").addClass("clicked");
 }
 else {
   $("#panel").css("max-height", "0px").removeClass("clicked");;   
  } 
});
```